# Using a variable to represent multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following part of a query:

```
Where id in (1,2,3) And country in('France','Italy','Spain')
```

I want to declare 2 variables and do it like:

```
Where id in (idsVaraible) And country in(countriesVriable)
```

It is more like substituting sql code in sql code to make my long query readable and more useful, is there any way to do this?

I think it's more like eval in java script.

Comment: How about adding a temp table variable and assigning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you need to pass these sets in as strings, one way would be dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(32) = '1,2,3';
DECLARE @countries VARCHAR(2000) = 'France,Italy,Spain';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... FROM ...
  WHERE id IN (' + @ids + ') AND country IN ('''
  + REPLACE(@countries, ',',''',''') + ''');';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Another way would be table-valued parameters. First create these types in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TVPids AS TABLE(ID INT);
CREATE TYPE dbo.TVPcountries AS TABLE(Country VARCHAR(255));
```

Now your stored procedure can take these types as input:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @i dbo.TVPids READONLY,
  @c dbo.TVPcountries READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ... FROM dbo.yourtable AS t
    INNER JOIN @i AS i ON i.ID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN @c AS c ON c.country = t.country;
END
GO
```

Now your app can pass these two parameters in as sets (e.g. from a `DataTable`) instead of building a comma-separated string or handling multiple parameters.

Comment: the first part is all i wanted :)

Comment: @user1590636 great, but you should learn about the second part as well. Sets are much more powerful and flexible than JSON strings and dynamic SQL.

Comment: @user1590636 of course they do. What makes you think a comma-separated string works and a set doesn't? Can you provide an example where you think this will be a problem (preferably as a different question)?

Comment: sure, the idea is i have a group by clauses to group by month week querter and year also by different dynamic number of columns, do you think working with sets would be a better option?

Comment: @user1590636 not enough information to answer your question, sorry.

Comment: i think i should try both and then decide whats better, i am stilll new to sql

Answer (score 1):

Please try using temp table variables:

```
DECLARE @tblID as TABLE(ID INT)
DECLARE @tblCountry as TABLE(Country NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @tblID VALUES (1),(2),(3)
INSERT INTO @tblCountry VALUES ('France'),('Italy'),('Spain')

WHERE id in (select ID from @tblID) And country in(select Country from @tblCountry)
```