# Sending multiple values to stored procedure and use it in IN operator

Tags: sql, reactjs, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a form where user could change some data in the database and there are few things he needs to provide, this is how the procedure looks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePrice] 
( 
    @type int, 
    @quality nvarchar(1000), 
    @dim1_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim1_to decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_to decimal(10, 2),
    @od_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @od_to decimal(10, 2),
    @price decimal(10, 2), 
    @price_m decimal(10, 2)
) 
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE list
    SET price = ISNULL(@price, price),
        price_m = ISNULL(@price_m, price_m)
    WHERE type = @type
      AND dim1 BETWEEN @dim1_from AND @dim1_to
      AND (dim2 BETWEEN @dim2_from AND @dim2_to OR @dim2_from IS NULL)
      AND od BETWEEN @od_from AND @od_to  
      AND quality IN (@quality)
END
```

This works ok, most of this data are numbers and I send only one number per variable, but the problem is with the variable `@quality`. In a database that is a string and when I send only one it works fine, but I want to send a multiple number of quality, so I tried sending it like 'quality1, quality2, quality3' but it didn't work and I think I understand why.

On this thread I found something that looks that can help me but I can't make it work

[Using a variable to represent multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850628/using-a-variable-to-represent-multiple-values)

This is what I made

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePrice] 
( 
    @type int, 
    @quality nvarchar(1000), 
    @dim1_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim1_to decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_to decimal(10, 2),
    @od_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @od_to decimal(10, 2),
    @price decimal(10, 2), 
    @price_m decimal(10, 2)
) 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'

    UPDATE lista_cevi
    SET price = ISNULL(' + @price + ', price),
        price_m = ISNULL(' + @price_m + ', price_m)
    WHERE type = ' + @type + '
      AND dim1 BETWEEN ' + @dim1_from + ' AND ' + @dim1_to + '
      AND (dim2 BETWEEN ' + @dim2_from + ' AND ' + @dim2_to + ' OR ' + @dim2_from + ' IS NULL)
      AND od BETWEEN ' + @od_from + ' AND ' + @od_to + '
      AND quality IN (''' + REPLACE(@quality, ',', ''',''') + ''')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

I'm using Postman to test it and most of the time I'm getting this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

I guess it has to do with the number variables, but I don't know how to fix it. When I delete most of it and leave only `WHERE quality IN (@quality)` it looks like it works, so the problem now is with other variables. I tried using `CAST()` to make them `nvarchar` but that also gave me some other kind of error.

Does anyone know how to fix it or is there some other way I can send
multiple data?

I am using React and NodeJs and the database is SQL Server.

The last solution I can think of is to map through all the qualities that are selected and call the procedure for every quality separately, not sure if that is the best idea?

Comment: Sounds like you need a Table Valued Parameter, then you can do `AND quality IN (SELECT value FROM @quality)`. Not sure exactly how you pass a TVP in NodeJS but there must be examples if you Google. You need a table type for this `CREATE TYPE dbo.SingleInt AS TABLE (Value int)` then use that type in your procedure `@quality dbo.SingleInt,`

Comment: Your first UPDATE is almost there (no need for Dynamic SQL).   As you know by now SQL Server does not support macro substitution.   Assuming @quality is a delimited string, just use string_split()  ....   AND quality IN (select value from string_split(@quality,',')) ...

Comment: As already said, the *correct* way to do this is a Table Valued Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If `@quality` is a CSV string then you could simply use [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) .
(if your Sql Server version supports it)

```
... 
AND quality IN (select TRY_CAST(value AS INT) as quality from STRING_SPLIT(@quality,','))
...
```

Comment: @lptr Maybe, but not sure what type to cast it in.  Oh well, can't be that many types.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account your front-end, it would be more natural and reliable to use a json array to pass these values to the procedure, and then parse @quality parameter in sql using `OPENJSON` operator.

For example, the value of your @quality parameter may looks like this:

'["quality1","quality2","quality3"]'

Then the procedure could take the following form:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ChangePrice] 
( 
    @type int, 
    @quality nvarchar(max), 
    @dim1_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim1_to decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @dim2_to decimal(10, 2),
    @od_from decimal(10, 2), 
    @od_to decimal(10, 2),
    @price decimal(10, 2), 
    @price_m decimal(10, 2)
) 
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE list
SET 
price=ISNULL(@price, price),
price_m=ISNULL(@price_m, price_m)
FROM list INNER JOIN OPENJSON(@quality) AS qualities ON list.quality = qualities.value
WHERE
    type=@type
    AND dim1 BETWEEN @dim1_from AND @dim1_to
    AND (dim2 BETWEEN @dim2_from AND @dim2_to OR @dim2_from IS NULL)
    AND od BETWEEN @od_from AND @od_to
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. No dynamic SQL.

It is using XQuery to tokenize a parameter, and convert it into a relational dataset.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, quality NVARCHAR(10), City VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (quality , City) VALUES
('10', 'Miami'),
('45', 'Orlando'),
('50', 'Dallas'),
('70', 'Houston');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @quality NVARCHAR(1000) = '22,45,50,105,'   -- here is your parameter
   , @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

DECLARE @parameter XML = TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(@quality, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML);

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS quality
   FROM @parameter.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN 
   rs ON t.quality = rs.quality;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | quality |  City   |
+----+---------+---------+
|  2 |      45 | Orlando |
|  3 |      50 | Dallas  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: xquery where a straight forward query would suffice?